# C++ Member "Smash::smash" is not a type name.

Tags: c++, object, constructor, reference

I need to pass a reference of an object to a constructor. I am passing a reference in the constructor, but it gives this error: Member "Smash::smash" is not a type name.

Smash.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Smash.h"
#include "Window.h"
#include "Input.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Render.h"

class Smash {
public:
    Smash & smash;
    Game game(smash);
};
```

Here is for example the constructor of the class Game declared:

```
#pragma once
#include "Smash.h"

class Game {
    public:
        Smash smash;
        Game(Smash & obj); //obj IS THE smash OBJECT
};
```

I don't understand. The parameter is a reference and also smash object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `Game.h` includes `Smash.h` and `Smash.h` includes `Game.h`, you have a circular dependency. One of them needs to be changed to include only a class declaration, but it's hard to say which one without seeing what you're doing with those types.

Comment: @Praetorian: Not the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly correctly use `pragma once` to avoid endless cycling in interependent headers.  Nevertheless, this is not sufficient.  You should also add a forward reference to `Game` in the `smash.h`

But there are a couple of other issues that make your example more difficult to get work:

- First, your `Smash` class has a member which is a reference to a `Smash`.  This means that you must also define constructors that initialize this reference.
- Second, your declaration of member `game()` doesn't use a valid type for parameter (typo ?).  This could be corrected by removing the parameter, assuming that `game()` works with the Smash object that invokes it.
- Third, if however you need a `Smash s` argument for `game()`, you'd define a function which takes an argument `Smash` by value.  You'd then also need a copy constructor.

Wrapping this all together, you get `smash.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include "Game.h"

class Game;             // Forward declaration for breaking the circular issue
class Smash {
public:
    Smash & smash;      // ==> needs to be initailized at construction
    Smash();            // <== therefore needs a constructor
    Game game(Smash s); // <== parameter needs a valid type
    Smash(const Smash &s);  // <== needs a copy constructor for param passing by value
};
```

The other header is ok.

**Funny note with MSVC2015:** If the forward declaration is missing, for a strange reason, the compiler reports error 3646 on the definition of `game()`.  This is misleading, as this error code is related to overriding which is not at all related to the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency. "Smash.h includes Game.h includes Smash.h includes Game.h" …

This cannot work.

The `#pragma once` will make it actually be either "Smash.h includes Game.h" or "Game.h includes Smash.h" (depending on which is included first from the .cpp file), but both headers do indeed require the declarations found within the other.

You're going to have to employ forward declarations to remove the dependency in at least one direction.

Comment: And `Smash.h` includes itself too :)

Comment: The other problem here is `Game game(smash)` isn't a member variable declaration.

Comment: @Praetorian Do you know where to do those forward declarations?

Comment: @PythonLover17 No, not without a [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Lightness already asked you for one in his very first comment)