# Passing parameter to a constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, oop, constructor

I created a class `vector` in C++ and then tried to use an vector object in a different class called `abc`.

What I want to do is define a object in class `abc` of type `vector`

Something like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class vector{
public:
    double icomponent=1;
    double jcomponent=1;
    double kcomponent=1;

    vector(double conI, double conJ, double conK){   //constructor
         icomponent = conI;
         jcomponent = conJ;
         kcomponent = conK;
    }
};

class abc{
    double i,j,k;
    vector velocity(i,j,k); 
};
```

However this code doesn't compile and throws this error:

```
member "abc::i" is not a type name
```

I don't understand what is causing the problem. Can anyone figure it out?

I tried searching online, but the closest I could find is-[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34029190/c-member-smashsmash-is-not-a-type-name?rq=1) , but that one was caused by some header file reference issues, and not related to this one.

Comment: What do you expect `vector velocity(i,j,k);` to do?

Comment: @ChrisMM I want to define a vector like velocity or accleration as an object to the class

Comment: @batchcoding____s The question is how you intend to use the class `abc`. Can you give an example of creating and using a `abc` object?

Comment: You need to read about the constructor in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: In a class definition, `vector velocity(i,j,k);` is the declaration of a member function, so `i`, `j`, and `k` must be types - and they aren't. While you *could* say `vector velocity = vector(i,j,k);`, that would be 1) undefined, since the values of `i`, `j`, and `k` are indeterminate at that point; and 2) probably not what you intended. Could you explain why you want this duplication of values?

Comment: @molbdnilo The values are not indeterminate if they are initialized by a constructor/aggregate initialization. But since everything is private, no object can be constructed anyway.

Comment: calling a class `vector` and having `using namespace std;` will certainly get you name collisions as you include this header in a file that also `#include <vector>`. `std::vector` is part of the C++ standard library: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do what you are trying to do in the way you've defined. Essentially, you cannot pass the variables `i`, `j`, and `k` to the constructor for `velocity` in such a manner. You need a constructor. Example:

```
class abc {
    double i, j, k;
    vector velocity;
public:
    abc( double i, double j, double k ) : i{i}, j{j}, k{k}, velocity{ i, j, k } {}
};
```

This uses the [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to initialize the three double variables, as well as the `velocity` variable.

Alternatively, as user17732522 mentions in the comments below, if your variables are public, you can do what you were trying with a slight modification:

```
class abc {
public:
    double i, j, k;
    vector velocity = vector{ i, j, k };
};
```

In order to use this method, you **must** initialize the `i`, `j` and `k` during construction of the object (either through a constructor, or through an aggregate initialization as shown below), otherwise, you will get undefined behaviour by utilizing uninitialized variables in the creation of the `velocity` object.

```
int main()
{
    abc a{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << a.velocity.icomponent << '\n'; // print 1
    std::cout << a.velocity.jcomponent << '\n'; // print 2
    std::cout << a.velocity.kcomponent << '\n'; // print 3
}
```

The problem with `vector velocity( i, j, k );` that you were trying, is that the C++ compiler interprets this as a function called `velocity` which returns a `vector`, then `i`, `j` and `k` are expected to be types (which of course they are not).

Comment: `vector velocity = vector(i,j,k);` is allowed and does the correct thing, just that because the other members were `private` and no constructor declared, there wouldn't have been a way to create an object.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I would say that the approach of @user17732522 is more preferable for what I want.

Comment: @user17732522, not disagreeing; perhaps some bad phrasing on my part. I meant in how OP tried to write it, and using a constructor is just simpler here.

Comment: @ChrisMM your 2nd example will not work.  Syntactically, the compiler will accept the code, but at runtime the `i`,  `j`, and `k` values will be *uninitialized* when the `vector` is constructed from them, causing *undefined behavior*. Your 1st example is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you sure? https://godbolt.org/z/YYWevrnb4 I agree that the constructor is the better way, but the second version does appear to work. Since `i`, `j`, and `k` will be initialized _before_ velocity, because that's the order they appear, it should be valid.

Comment: @ChrisMM if you create the object like `abc a;` instead, then yes, they will be uninitialized: https://godbolt.org/z/jY9s4hhaP

Comment: @RemyLebeau, true, I should have given an example. I'll update the answer to clarify usage.